# Through VB.NET, how do you add and edit code modules of an Excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: excel, vb.net, module, office-interop

I am updating company software written in VB.Net. Our data is stored in MYSQL. One of the features I am trying to update is the ability to create reports. Now these reports are to be generated as excel workbooks by the software. With some difficulty I have gotten to the part where I can create excel workbooks and insert data and even use some excel features through VB.Net Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. However, I want to have the ability to create macros/hard coding directly through interop which will make these reports much more beneficial. I would like the ability to use both worksheet level modules and general code modules. I have tried to play with the syntax, but I don't think I am even close. I can't seem to find any clarification on the topic. Thank you for your help.

```
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("CALL reports_productionschedule();", connection)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        connection.Open()
        adapter.Fill(table)
        connection.Close()


        Dim app As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()

        Call DataTableToExcel(table, wb, "ProductionSchedule")'sub I built to print out Headers 
        'and Data from a datatable to an excel file

        app.Visible = True

        Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        wb.Activate()
        ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        ws.Activate()

        ws.Range("A1:ZZ100000").Columns.AutoFit()

        ws.Range("A1:ZZ100000").AutoFilter2(Field:=1)

        app.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 0
        app.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
        app.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
        
        'everything works to this point. here are things I have tried without success

        Dim strcode As String
        strcode = "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
        Dim nmod As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Module = wb.Modules.Add(strcode)

        app.Modules.Add(strcode)

        'I know you can programmatically write code in another workbook through excel, I figure 
        'there has to be a way in VB.Net

        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
        Dim linenum As Long
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(2)
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    
        With CodeMod

        linenum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines linenum, "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)"


        'But none of these key words comes up in VB.Net intellisense
```

Comment: "However, I want to have the ability to create macros/hard coding directly through interop which will make these reports much more beneficial." What are you trying to get Excel to do? You have MS SQL Server, so can you use Reporting Services reports? If you have complex report UI requirements, you might be better off with Power BI instead of reinventing the wheel in Excel?

Comment: I am sorry. That was a typographical error on my part. Our data is stored in a MYSQL database. I am not sure what tools there are to create UI directly from MYSQL. The reason to run macros in these excel sheets is to enable our users to complete some simplified tasks.  My company is not the most technologically literate and my job is often to simplify tasks. Some of the fields which these reports produce need to be edited by select users, and the database then needs to reflect those updates. This is the main reason for adding code modules/macros to these excel workbooks.

Comment: Honestly, that sounds overly complex. You should build the data editing capability in the .NET application. Then, if you want to export data to Excel to act as a reporting layer, that's fine.

Comment: I understand and agree. But in my world, nothing is ever ideal, just hopefully better than yesterday. I feel like there has to be an easy way to set a string in vb.net as a line of code in a module in excel. This seems like a relatively simple task, though I admit it is not conventional nor often ideal.

Comment: Instead of writing code in .NET to save to a database, you're asking how to automate the writing of code in Excel VBA. How could that possibly be a "relatively simple task"? How can that be more maintainable? Debuggable? This is definitely an XY Problem. At worst, why not just write the code in an Excel template, directly in VBA, and write your data to the template?

Comment: I do already have my code in VBA in a template. I want VB.Net to recreate my template, by copying the code from a string stored within. Because there are 10+ users who need to have access to this information, I don't want them to have to make sure their excel copies are all maintained on 10+ machines. I want VB.Net to be able to spit out a copy, that I can keep maintained and won't require users to have full and continual access to some network drive.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus). You can [write VBA code](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/VBA) to the Excel file.

> EPPlus supports Creating, Reading and Writing VBA. Execution/Interpretation of VBA code is not supported. Remember that the package must be saved with the extension xlsm. A VBA project is created by the CreateVBAProject() method of the ExcelWorkbook class. This enables you to write VBA code to the project...

The linked page offers an example in C#, which should be easy to convert to VB.NET:

```
private static void VBASample1(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
{
   ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
   //Add a worksheet.
   var ws=pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("VBA Sample");
   ws.Drawings.AddShape("VBASampleRect", eShapeStyle.RoundRect);            
   //Create a vba project             
   pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
   //Now add some code to update the text of the shape...
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendLine("Private Sub Workbook_Open()");
   sb.AppendLine("    [VBA Sample].Shapes(\"VBASampleRect\").TextEffect.Text = \"This text is set from VBA!\"");
   sb.AppendLine("End Sub");
   pck.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = sb.ToString();            

   //And Save as xlsm
   pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample15-1.xlsm"));
}
```